# Python - Want to change header logo based on url selection

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I would like to change the logo of a website based on which menu is currently activated/seen by the user browsing the website.

For instance I have www.urltowebsite.com/menu1 = Header Logo 1
And then I have www.urltowebsite.com/menu2 = Header Logo 2

And on top of this I want to add an else statement stating that: If any other menu is selected, use header logo 3.

How can I make this possible with Python? I cant seem to wrap my head around what to define where and how to call up the different functions on the HTML website.

Oh and I insist doing this with Python. And preferably without any framework such as Django. But if needs be I can install web.py

EDIT:

Am I forced to go with php then? I would like to once and for all start utilizing Python on my web projects. 
The website is made in simple HTML as I said first. The Javascript functions are only used to serve the HTML menu's through AJAX. Again this does not matter much for what I am trying to do, as menu's have classes and I can define those in php and thus change my logo/header. 
What I want to do is to use Python in this instance. Here is a code snippet from the site:

```
<div id="header">
    <span class="title"><img src="http://www.url.com/subfolder/images/logo.png"/>
        </span>
    </div>
```

And some more relevant to this:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#slider" id="menu_slider">001</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" id="menu_about">002</a></li>
<li><a href="#application" id="menu_portfolio">003</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" id="menu_contact">004</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" id="menu_reel">005</a></li>
<li><a href="#contactresell" id="menu_awards">006</a></li>
<li><a href="#handel" id="link">007</a></li>
<li><a href="#faq" id="menu_faq">008</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So can I use python here?

Comment: How are you presenting the site? What is constructing the page in `menu1`, `menu2`, etc? Is it plain HTML or being constructed by Python?

Comment: The page is constructed in plain HTML. Basically url changes are just #1 #2 etc. Everything is server as HTML, but the menu's are dynamically generated by javascript. However this should not have anything to say since I can def and call up functions in the main HTML.

Comment: You can call Javascript from HTML, but you can't call Python from HTML. You'd have to generate the HTML using server-side Python. And you're saying the menus are generated from Javascript? Then Python can't get involved at any stage.

Comment: What you say still doesn't really make sense.  You can't just inject Python code into an arbitrary webpage.

Comment: I just added an EDIT to my explanation. Maybe that helps?

Comment: @PythonRocks: If you want to use Python in your web projects, anyone would *strongly* recommend you use an existing web framework such as Django. It would make both presenting your pages and storing information in a database much easier and more intuitive, and prevent you from having to reinvent the wheel at every turn. (This is not specific to Python- the same would be true of PHP).

Comment: Though in this specific case, what not have the Javascript change the header logo, the same function that serves the HTML menu?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking to do the wrong thing the wrong way.

In order to change the logo based on the URL in Python , you need Python to generate the page and know what that url is.

There are two ways to do that in Python:

- Use an existing Web Framework
- Write your own Web Framework

"Python" doesn't know or care what your URL is - the frameworks and support libraries ( Django, Pyramid, Bottle, Flash, Tornado, Twisted, etc) figure out what the URL is by an integration with an underlying web server ( though some have their own webserver coupled in ).  Similarly, PHP doesn't really know or care what the URL is - that information comes from an integration with Apache or FCGI/Nginx/etc.   PHP tends to ship with most/all of that integration done.  It's also worth noting that PHP is not just a language, but a web framework.  Python is just a language.

Most Python frameworks will be written to the WSGI spec and have a "request" object that has all the data you want ( and many use the WebOb librbary for that ).

If you plan on doing everything with static HTML files, then you have a few options:

- have a single static directory.  use javascript to figure out the addressbar location, and render the corresponding logo / write the headers & footers.
- have a "template" directory of all your HTML.  use a Python script build a static version of each website with the custom headers/footers and configure your webserver to serve a different one for each domain.

Comment: But doing the page in Python would then mean starting from scratch, and utilizing Django or some other web framework right?

Comment: Regardless of which language(s) you choose , you'll need to update the header on all the pages.  This could be done by hand or automated.  You could strip the headers out, turn it into templates with inline functions, includes, or template variables, or really anything.  it's up to you.  You'd need to do this whatever option you choose - PHP, Python or Javascript.  

Another option you have is to do server-side filtering, where the server regexes stuff out and replaces the headers on the fly.  You could do that with sed under apache.

Answer (score 0):

No, Python cannot run inside the HTML web page.  If you're really serving plain HTML pages then you must use javascript to execute code in the browser once the page is loaded.  However, since you mention using AJAX, it sounds like it's *not* really true that you're serving plain HTML but rather have some server side code.  If so, that server side code is the place to put your HTML-construction logic.  To know the best way to do that, you would have to describe what's happening on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't used it, I have heard that the [pyhp](http://pyhp.sourceforge.net) project more or less provides php-like embedded functionality for python.

Comment: So you get what PHP tries to get rid off?

Comment: @Matthias Unless I'm mistaken, the question regarded the possibility of embedding Python in a webpage - as far as I know, pyhp does this, I think it's fair to mention it.

Comment: Yes PHP does this. But every professional PHP developer uses template engines instaead. The unhealthy mix of HTML and code is not good - not even in PHP.